# Plot stoping tkinter Windows when it gets updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What im trying to do is draw a plot inside a second Tkinter window, a TopLevel(), when i draw this figure inside my second window every second, the time it gets updated, it stops just for a little bit of time the UI.

```
#Here is where i create my second window, gets trigger by a button on my main window.
def WindowEnergiaElectrica():
   global OpenWindowEE
   global WindowFloat1
   if DoOnce(OpenWindowEE):
      OpenWindowEE +=1
      print(OpenWindowEE)
      WindowFloat1 = Toplevel(window)
      WindowFloat1.title("Energia Electrica")
      WindowFloat1.geometry("1400x1000")
      WindowFloat1.resizable(False, False)
      WindowFloat1.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ClosingEEWindow)
      UIEnergiaElectrica(WindowFloat1)
```

```
#Here is my timer every second
def countdown():
   global Timer 
   Num =+ 1  
   if Num != 0:
      Timer += 1
      XList.append(Timer)
      #set_text_by_button(str(Timer))
      YList.append(AllRegisters())
      plot()
      window.update()
      window.after(1000, countdown)

   if Timer >= 10:
      XList.pop(0)
      YList.pop(0)
```

```
#Here is where i draw my plot
def plot(): 
   global WindowFloat1
   # the figure that will contain the plot 
   fig = Figure(figsize = (8, 5)) 
  
   # list of squares 
   #y = [i**2 for i in range(101)] 
  
   # adding the subplot 
   plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111) 
  
   # plotting the graph 
   plot1.plot(XList, YList)
   #plot1.draw()
   
  
   # creating the Tkinter canvas 
   # containing the Matplotlib figure 
   canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = WindowFloat1)   
   canvas.draw() 
  
   # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window 
   canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() 
  
   # creating the Matplotlib toolbar 
   # toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window) 
   # toolbar.update() 
  
   # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window 
   canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x= 350, y=150)
   canvas.get_tk_widget().delete()
```

I tried just to delete the WindowFloat1.mainloop() it gets all the events from the second window, but instead i want to still work in both windows not cancelling the events from each one